# Kodi 17 Raspberry Pi ControlImage Not Showing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kodi

I have an issue where my ControlImage is not showing on Kodi 17 on Pis. It works on my Mac though so its hard to pinpoint if is a raspberry pi specific issue. My code looks like this.

```
##Create Window
__display_window__ = xbmcgui.Window(12005)

##Banner Image
url ='http://www.example.com/image.png'
__banner_image__ = xbmcgui.ControlImage(__display_window__.getWidth(), __display_window__.getHeight(), 500, 200, url)
__display_window__.addControl(__banner_image__)

##Example with text
 __text_title__ = xbmcgui.ControlTextBox(0, __display_window__.getHeight() - 10, 1130, 50)
 __display_window__.addControl(__text_title__)
__text_title__.setText( 'Watch at home on ' + name + '!!!' )
```

Does anyone have an idea of what this could be happening?

Comment: Anything in the logfile? And don't use  __variable_name__ it should be only variable_name

Comment: @Razze "variable_name it should be only variable_name" ? Can you please clarify